# How to show horizontal ellipsis at bottom of the text

Tags: html, css

I'm using a HTML Entity to show three dots (...) to indicate uses that there was having more text. There were other ways to show this through CSS (`text-overflow: ellipsis;`), but I have some limitations to use CSS style.

The issue is, the ellipsis is showing in the middle of the text - I need it the same as how manual three dots appear after a text like,

```
Many people have sent language examples over the years...
```

My current output:

[image]

horizontal ellipsis

```html
<p><span>Sample Text:</span>Many people have sent language examples over the years, but we want more! We'd love to add more examples&#8230;</p>
```

Comment: Have you tried just wriitng "..." in the text? also what is everything wrapped with?

Comment: Can you share the css code as well

Comment: there was no CSS code for this

Comment: in the snippet it looks fine

Comment: @Michael Same after adding "..."

Comment: When I run the snippet I see the ... in the correct place (aligned with the bottom of the text). What browser are you using?

Comment: try taking it out of the P tag and using a div maybe

Comment: @ATP I'm not sure how snippet worked here. I just made a simple HTML file without any CSS and there I saw this issue.

Comment: @Daisy Chome & FF

Comment: @Michael Same on DIV as well.

Comment: are you sure that you are not running it with css? maybe a browser extension? try to open a new blank html file with the code above in incognito because it works fine for me.

Comment: @DanielSmith can you add the parent element and it's corresponding `css`? And did the snippet here show the same result to you? (centered vertically?)

Comment: @ATP same with incognito as well and yes, I'm not using any css

Comment: @Kyojimaru The snippet (here) looks good to me, not sure how it's work here

Comment: @DanielSmith then mostly it's the parent `style` which got applied to the `<p>` element, maybe you can try encapsulating the `...` inside a `span` and check it's styling using the DevTools and check for any style that may cause the problem.

Answer (score 0):

[ToolJS](https://github.com/REDEAKAA/ToolJS) is a Utility JavaScript library with functions that solve things like this and ease your work flow.

It contains a "Str" module that manipulates a string, and amongst them is the **.truncate** function which will give you want you need.

How to use it

Get the code either through its [CDN](https://unpkg.com/@redeakaa/tooljs@1.0.1/dist/umd/tooljs.min.js) or [NPM](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@redeakaa/tooljs) and use as shown below

```js
var Str = ToolJS.export("Str");
    
    var myString = "Many people have sent language examples over the years, but we want more! We'd love to add more examples";
    
    var newString = Str.truncate(myString, {
        limit: 40, // this is the number of characters you want to show in your string
        replacement: "..." // this is the replacement string
    });
    
    // Or you could do a shorthand implentation using the same method
    
    var newString = Str.truncate(myString, 40, "...");
    
    // To show it on your DOM
    
    var DOM = ToolJS.export("DOM");
    
    DOM.html("p", `<p><span>Sample Text:</span>${newString}</p>`);
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/@redeakaa/tooljs@1.0.1/dist/umd/tooljs.min.js"></script>
<p><span>Sample Text:</span>Many people have sent language examples over the years, but we want more! We'd love to add more examples</p>
```

Comment: Same things I'm doing through custom JS -

Comment: like, var newString = Str.truncate(myString, 40, "&#8230;");

Comment: and the three dots appear in the middle...that is the issue

Comment: You don't have to use the unicode, just give it the dots, in character format, and you're good to go

Comment: The unicode you're trying to use is a character that does not sit on the baseline, so it don't using it will be a good idea

Comment: I have put a snippet with the working example, check it out